# Which interactions produce entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I'm trying to better understand which kinds of interactions cause the entanglement.

I do understand how it works in the cases of non-relativistic spin systems. For example, evolving a pure state in time with the Hamiltonian of the form $\vec{\sigma}^{(j)} \cdot \vec{\sigma}^{(j+1)}$ will likely result in an entangled state.

What about the following physical systems:

1. Non-relativistic QM of a finite number of particles with a Hamiltonian having only coordinate dependence (no spins).
2. Same as 1., but with only spin-spin and coordinate-coordinate interactions (nothing like spin-orbital interaction).
3. Relativistic field theory describing interactions of fields with zero/nonero spin. Importantly, such a theory is manifestly local.

Which terms in these cases cause entanglement during the time evolution?

I would also expect that this question may be related to another one:

What are the conditions on the Hamiltonian for its eigenstates (or, at least, the ground state) to be unentangled?